# Could anyone help me with CRC calculation reveng

Tags: algorithm, reverse-engineering, modbus, crc

I am struggling with crc calculation of data comming from an old machine. Data seams to be modbus communication, but none of my attempts succeded. I tried different algos with different poly, xorin, xorout and so on... I can interpret data itself but have no clue how to calculate CRC... I tried https://crccalc.com/ and https://reveng.sourceforge.io/readme.htm

Maybe someone could hint me...

```
02 2e 05 0f 01 04 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 8e 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6f 01 00 00 00 00 68 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 8f 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6f 01 00 00 00 00 6e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 91 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6f 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 92 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 66 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 92 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 66 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 93 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 6e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 95 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 95 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 96 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6e 01 00 00 00 00 86 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 97 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 6e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 04 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 98 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 78 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 99 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9a 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 86 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9a 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 86 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9b 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6d 01 00 00 00 00 8e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9d 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9d 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 01 00 00 00 00 7e 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 9e 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 01 00 00 00 00 86 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 a0 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 01 00 00 00 00 96 
02 2e 05 0f 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c3 1d 00 00 01 16 02 00 0b 03 00 a1 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 6c 01 00 00 00 00 9e
```

Comment: There is no CRC in your example data.

Comment: This isn't a Modbus frame either - function `2e` isn't a known function and is out of user functions range, therefore it can't be neither a Modbus request or reply. How do you obtain these data? Serial link? TCP/UDP/IP (and which port is used, then)? Which application / library is used?

Comment: Data is obtained via serial and the third byte (0x05) is the machine address

Comment: Each of this packets is obtained by sending 02 07 05 0a 10 00 21 and the second byte is the packet length. If the data contains 0x02 then there is additional 0x00 appended - this is what I found...

Comment: That does not look like a Modbus request (or response). Without more info (i.e. what is the "machine") you are relying upon someone recognising the byte sequence (possible but the machine may be using a custom protocol not used anywhere else...).

Comment: Thank you. I finally found the Siemens USS Protocol document - https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/253/24178253/att_101238/v1/uss_24178253_spec_76.pdf which seems to describe exactly the structure of the sample data, but still cannot figure out the way to calculate the last byte which is the CRC called BCC. According to the document it should be simple XOR of the packet data starting with 0x00...

Comment: You are right; the last byte in each line within your example data does not appear to be a BCC as defined in the document you linked ([my test](https://go.dev/play/p/YDy51Y4CsED)).